# black screen in andengine when i try to use the x,y offset in TextureRegion

Tags: android, andengine, textures

im using GLES2. When i create my region with:

BitmapTextureAtlasTextureRegionFactory.createFromAsset(Atlas3, this, "columna.png",0 ,0);

Everything works fine. The atlas is 128x256, and the texture is 100x256 or so, so i'd like to use the x offset because otherwise my collisions are messed with box2d. Problem is i get a black screen whenever i change the offset to anything other than 0,0.

Any hints?

Answer (score 0):

use 256+(offset) instead of 256 as height of texture.

---

SA